# Non canonical expression of an eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

In "The Elements of Statistical Learning" 3rd edition, by Hastie, on page 154 the symmetric matrix $S_\lambda$ is decomposed as:

$\mathbf{S}_\lambda = \sum_{k=1}^N \rho_k(\lambda)\mathbf{u}_k\mathbf{u}_k^T$

$\mathbf{u}_k$ and $\rho_k$ being eigen vectors / values of $S_\lambda$, and $\lambda$ a parameter used in the computation of $S_\lambda$.

This does not look like the usual eigendecomposition of a matrix $\mathbf{S}_\lambda=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{Q}^{-1}$ as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix for example. I did some numerical trials in R and found that only the symmetric matrices I provided could be decomposed that way.

My questions then are:

- What are the minimal prerequisites to perform this decomposition ? Is it just symmetry ?
- Does this decomposition has a particular name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the symmetric eigenvalue decomposition:

http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/thm_sed.html

Answer (score 0):

The general condition for such a decomposition is that the $S_λ$ are normal, that is, the commute with their adjoint matrices.

Additionally, if as written the vectors $u_k$ are independent of the parameter $λ$, you need that the matrices $S_λ$ commute among each other so that they share a common refinement of eigenspaces.

One can, I believe, combine both conditions as $S_λS_\mu^*=S_\mu^*S_λ$.